# Use custom url for defining environment in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, sh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

### Current configuration:

I am working with gitlab-ci. I currently have two stages in my gitlab-ci.yml file, one for building and one for deploying. The jobs are running successfully.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
 - build
 - deploy

d_build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - my-runner
  script:
    - echo "Build"
    - sh testScript.sh
d_review:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: (INSERT URL HERE)
  tags:
    - my-runner
  script:
    - echo "Foo"
```

*Gitlab Runner Vesion*: 11.7.0

*OS*: windows/amd64

---

### Desired behavior:

The *testScript.sh* shell file is generating a url which I would like to use in the url field in the environment, in the deploy stage.

From the operations pane in gitlab, in the environments page, I would like to be able to select the "Open live environment" option for me to visualize the url generated by the .sh file. How can this be achieved?

I thought of two possible ways but I am not sure on how either of them can be achieved. Would it be possible, from "testScript.sh", to set up an environmental variable in the build stage so that it can then be picked up in the deploy stage?

Alternatively, if the "testScript.sh" file were to create a text file containing the url, how could I instruct the deploy stage to read from the text file and use its contents to define a variable for it to then be used in the url field?

---

### What I tried:

As a test, I tried setting up a variable in *variables* in the build stage:

```
stages:
 - build
 - deploy

d_build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - my-runner
  script:
    - echo "Build"
    - sh testScript.sh
  variables:
    url_endpoint: "myendpoint"
```

Modifying the url as follows:

```
d_review:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://localhost:1234&endpoint=$url_endpoint
  tags:
    - my-runner
  script:
    - echo "Foo"
```

However this did not work, there was a blank in the final url instead of "myendpoint", which tells me I am missing something in how variables are propagated too. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please elaborate what kind of urls and how many different urls your .sh script can generate.

Comment: @mles The .sh script generates one url only. The static part of the url looks something like `https://localhost:5939/mywebpage/index.html?id=` , the dynamic part follows the static part and is composed of alphanumerical characters.

Comment: see my updated answer for a further suggestion

Comment: @Paolo Please help me on the same problem, please check the link once https://stackoverflow.com/q/64641302/3946958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of running the job, the url has to be set. You can not set the environment url in a job before the deployment:

> The url parameter can use any of the defined CI variables, including predefined,
>    secure variables and .gitlab-ci.yml variables. You however cannot use variables
>    defined under script.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#environmenturl

You could use a javascript redirect as workaround:

```
d_build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - my-runner
  script:
    - echo "Build"
    - UUID=$(sh testScript.sh)
    - echo '<html><head><script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace("https://localhost:5939/mywebpage/index.html?id='$UUID'");</script></head></html>' > redirect.html

d_review:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://localhost:5939/mywebpage/redirect.html
  tags:
    - my-runner
  script:
    - echo "Foo"
```

This creates a `redirect.html` which redirects to your localhost url with the parameter created by `testScript.sh`. If the creation of the `redirect.html` fails due to character escaping, try to put the line starting with `echo` into your sh script.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very clever solution. I was thinking of doing similar with Node.js but this is indeed simpler. Do you know how this method can be used to open a file on a drive? Such as having the url in environment as  `file:///H:/Documents/myfolder/redirect.html` ?

Comment: @mles , Could you please help me on the same problem , please check the link :- https://stackoverflow.com/q/64641302/3946958

Answer (score 1):

Variables in GitLab are not passed between jobs. There are more people that are asking for if this can be done though:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/47517

I haven't used environments myself in GitLab, but from this link it looks like the environment: url is quite limited in what you can do with it:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#environmenturl

It should be possible to use the API to manually trigger a new pipeline from your build job:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#triggering-a-pipeline

They have some features that makes it easier if you are a paying customer, but I think it should be possible to achieve what you want anyway. You could use something like this from your d_build job:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"token":"token", "ref":"my-branch", "variables": {"url_endpoint": "myendpoint"}}' \
 https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:iid/trigger/pipeline
```

You would have to get an access token:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

And you can send it to the GitLab script using variables or protected variables:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#variables

Your gitlab-ci file would then look something like:

```
stages:
 - build
 - deploy

d_build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - my-runner
  script:
    - echo "Build"
    - sh testScript.sh
    - [curl script here]
except:
  variables:
    - $url_endpoint

d_review:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: $url_endpoint
  tags:
    - my-runner
  script:
    - echo "Foo"
  only:
    variables:
      - $url_endpoint
```

The "only" and "except" keywords should make it so that only the build job is run when you push, and the d_review is only run when this variable is set which should only be there when the job is triggered.

I haven't tested this but I hope that it gives you something to work with. I really hope that there is a simpler solution that this!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your suggestion. The deploy stage is triggered correctly with the curl request, however when I try to `echo $url_endpoint` in the script it is not printed, meaning that the variable is not correctly propagated. The web page displayed in the environment section is also not the correct one.

Comment: From [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/47517#note_130510408) comment it looks like it might be possible somehow though

Comment: Whenever your build is triggered, gitlab parses what is set in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` as of *now*. Gitlab does *not* parse the `.gitlab-ci.yml` again whenever `d_review` is run. This means `$url_endpoint` is empty from the beginning and stays empty for this pipeline. Even worse: on the next build, `$url_endpoint` has the value from the previous build.

Comment: @MrBerta, Please help me on the same problem , please check the link once https://stackoverflow.com/q/64641302/3946958

Comment: To pass variables to a pipeline by CURL, you may use something like this: `curl -X POST --fail -F token=<your-token> -F ref=review -F "variables[UPSTREAM_BACKEND_TAG]=commit-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" -F "variables[UPSTREAM_FRONTEND_TAG]=some_value" -F "variables[UPSTREAM_SLUG]=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" -F "variables[UPSTREAM_ACTION]=destroy" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/<project-id>/trigger/pipeline"`. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#making-use-of-trigger-variables. These variables (`UPSTREAM_xx` in the example) will be abailable in the triggered job.