# GItlab CI :- How to create the multiple apk(like development, staging and production) in Android using the Gitlab-CI?

Tags: android, gitlab, apk, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am able to create the single build(apk) like **`debug.apk`** using the Gitlab-CI by below approach in Gitlab.
Inside my **`.gitlab-ci.yml`** , I have done this entry.Please check it once,

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - dev-ci
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
```

And I have created the **`docker`** image and got the build (apk) on each push on the Gitlab.

My question is that can we set the different stages like **`Development`** , **`Staging`** and **`Production`** which point out different **`BASE_URL`** of the application. I have also searched out in the documents but did not get the solution.Please help me on it. Thanks

Comment: You can do this either by using build types or build flavors as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).I think build types would be the best case here. Then, in the CI job, you need to execute the three separate assemble commands to get your APKs: assembleDebug, assembleStaging, assembleRelease.

Edit: Using flavors / build types allows you to define additional source sets where you can place your various URLs.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Can you please give me the example of it like one apk pointing Google URL, second one pointing YAHOO and last one is pointing StackOverflow.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mles Solution works but it relies on setting an environment variable. This is great for the CI usecase but if you *also* want to quickly build a dev/staging/release version locally, you should use build types or flavors instead. Check out the [Configure build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) guide for further information.

The following example shows how to achieve this with build types, but using flavors is also very similar.

### Configuring different API base URLs using gradle build types and source sets

#### Add an additional build type

The default gradle configuration should already contain a `debug` and `release` build type. Add an additional `staging` build type by adding this lines in your app module's `build.gradle` file inside the `buildTypes`:

```
staging {
    initWith debug
}
```

Your build.gradle should then look like this:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        staging {
            initWith debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Execute a gradle sync afterwards (by pressing the "Sync Project with Gradle" button with the Elephant logo at the top).

#### Add additional source sets

You can tell gradle to package specific code and resources for specific build configurations. In our example, we will create an `ExampleConfig` file which contains the base URl, for each build type.

```
object ExampleConfig {
    const val BASE_ULR = "http://example.com/"
}
```

In your code, you can just reference this file to access the base URL. Depending on the selected build type, gradle will then automatically use the correct version of the file.

For this, add the following folders inside your modules `src` folder (for example inside `\app\src`):

- `debug/java`
- `staging/java`
- `release/java`

There, create the `ExampleConfig` class / object which contains a `baseUrl` String with different values. The result should look like this:

It should look like this:
[image: Final source sets]

#### Changing the CI job

In your CI, build the different versions by calling assemble with different configurations:

- `./gradlew assembleDebug`
- `./gradlew assembleStaging`
- `./gradlew assembleRelease`

The final gitlab-ci configuration in your example should look like this:

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - dev-ci
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleStaging assembleRelease
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
```

Comment: I have used the below @mles's **yml**, Is it right ? Because it is working now.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I updated the config as well. If you use the different source sets and specifcy the URL in code, you don't have to specify a `BASE_URL` in your `yml`. You can execute the various `assemble` tasks in one build step like I showed or split it like @mles suggested it.

Comment: @Alexandra Can you please help me on one doubt that how to create the **shared runner** of **gitlab-ci** because yet now build which is generating is system dependent means when my system is on then i am getting the build otherwise getting fail while creating the build.Please help me on it ..Thanks

Comment: I suggest you create a new question since this is not related to android or your initial problem. This would also allow other people to give you better answers

Comment: Ok give me 30 minutes of it..Will post new question..But do you have any idea of it? Are you getting my point? Please let me know , i will elaborate more

Comment: If I understand you correct, you have general hosting questions. Usually, if you require a self-hosted runner, it should run on a dedicated computer or server which is always on instead of a local machine. Alternatively, rent a (virtual) server online and setup a runner there.

Comment: Yes you are in right direction. I have seen in **Gitlap-CI** that there are two types of runner one which we can create or say custom another one  is the **Shared runner** which **Gitlab** manage with it self.. So i am asking about it..Thanks man

Comment: Can you please help me on this query :- https://stackoverflow.com/q/64678868/3946958

Comment: Can you please guide me on Jenkin CI-CD configuration for the android. I just want to config my remote server to create my apk and testing,Please help me on it Thanks

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Sorry, I don't have much experience with Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

Either set `BASE_URL` within the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

development:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - dev-ci
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDevelopment
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
  variables:
    BASE_URL: "https://stackoverflow.com"

staging:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - dev-ci
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleStaging
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
  variables:
    BASE_URL: "https://yahoo.com"

production:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - dev-ci
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleProduction
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/
  variables:
    BASE_URL: "https://google.com"
```

You must create the Android Flavours `development`, `staging`, `production` in your gradle file, and make them use the `BASE_URL` environment variable.

Or, just like [Alexander Hoffmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2258611/alexander-hoffmann) is suggesting, do this all in your gradle file without setting variables in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: Thanks @mles.. How does the BASE_URL of my .yml file will relate with Android Flavours?  Please guide me on it. Thanks

Comment: Please google how to use environment variables within gradle.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, it worked Can you please edit your **yml** file because it is invalid, i have edited the yml and created the flavour and it works thanks for suggestion again

Comment: Can you please guide me on Jenkin CI-CD configuration for the android. I just want to config my remote server to create my apk and testing,Please help me on it Thanks